# Mutually recursive modules in practice

Tags: haskell, ghc

Given that making GHC compile mutually recursive modules is a bit laborious, I'd like to know how this affects the use of mutually recursive modules in practice?

Do people try to avoid them? 
Do we have any figures, for example, how many packages on Hackage use this feature?

Comment: Probably you'll find only a few packages making a use of mutually recursive modules. However, I have the felling that, even if GHC supported them perfectly, there would be still only a few of them. My guess is that module mutual recursion can be a symptom of bad design: one was not able to define a standalone module for the other to depend on, so the interfaces are broken and mutual dependencies arise.

Comment: As it stands this question isn't fit for SO. Provide an explicit *programming problem*. If you want to ask about statistics of GHC you should probably use some mailing list or irc channel related to haskell/ghc or use haskell's chat here on SO but not a SO question.

Comment: It's rare enough and hairy enough that I wouldn't be shocked if it eventually went away.